# Bind mount docker client binary from MacOS to docker-dind image

Tags: linux, macos, docker, md5, docker-volume

```
#1
On my Mac
$ uname -a
Darwin 19.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Mon Aug 31 22:12:52 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
 $ md5 `which docker`
MD5 (/usr/local/bin/docker) = d0da0db0b35f2d8ccad29296c297faf3
```

```
#2
In a dind container 
$ docker run --rm --privileged --name dind1 -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  docker:1.8-dind sh
/ # docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.8.3
 API version:  1.20
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   f4bf5c7
 Built:        Mon Oct 12 18:01:15 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Error response from daemon: 400 Bad Request: malformed Host header
/ # which docker
/usr/local/bin/docker
/ # md5sum /usr/local/bin/docker
73804379c30833e79345dced46f55e91  /usr/local/bin/docker
```

```
#3
To avoid "Error response from daemon: 400 Bad Request: malformed Host header" I need the docker client binary for the Mac OS (not Linux), so I do a bind mount
 $ docker run --rm --privileged --name dind1 -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker docker:1.8-dind sh
/ # md5sum /usr/local/bin/docker
1abd4fcb4e4bddf17574e2e85d9a42eb  /usr/local/bin/docker
/ # docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        4484c46d9d
 Built:             Wed Sep 16 17:00:06 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.13
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       4484c46d9d
  Built:            Wed Sep 16 17:07:04 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.3.7
  GitCommit:        8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Question:
Why are the /usr/local/bin/docker md5sums different in #1 and #3 ?

Comment: Are you actually getting the `docker` binary from the hidden Linux VM?  (If it was the MacOS binary, you'd get something like "exec format error"; bind-mounting binaries from the host doesn't work reliably and it's better to install them in your image.)

Comment: I tried this on my mac. #1, #3 are actually different, one is ELF the other is Mach-O. Maybe there are undocumented issues on bind overriding individual files. By the way, you could use dind image without the bind. Just use latest version not 1.8.

Comment: Ok will try it out and post the results.